# Java Spring boot, Spring batch, multi datasource circular references error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a little test project to config several data sources on a spring batch, boot application.

As far as I see is ok, but I always have the **jpaMappingContext  does not support circular references error.** .

**This is my dependencies.** .

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**My database config**

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"entityManagerFactory"})
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"dataSource"})
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean result = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    result.setPackagesToScan("juanjo.domain.entity");
    result.setDataSource(dataSource);

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter obj = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    obj.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    obj.setShowSql(true);
    obj.setGenerateDdl(false);
    result.setJpaVendorAdapter(obj);
    return result;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceMaster", destroyMethod = "close")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db-1")
    public DataSource dataSourceMaster() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceOrigin", destroyMethod = "close")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db-O")
    public DataSource dataSourceOrigin() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceReplica", destroyMethod = "close")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db-2")
    public DataSource dataSourceReplica() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean()
    @DependsOn({"dataSourceMaster", "dataSourceOrigin", "dataSourceReplica"})
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        RoutingDataSource result = new RoutingDataSource();
        Map<Object, Object> params = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        params.put(DbType.MASTER, dataSourceMaster());
        params.put(DbType.REPLICA1, dataSourceReplica());
        params.put(DbType.ORIGIN, dataSourceOrigin());
        result.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourceMaster());
        result.setTargetDataSources(params);
        result.afterPropertiesSet();
        return result;
    }

}
```

**My job:**

```
@Configuration
public class CountryBatch {
    @Autowired
    private CountryWriter countryWriter;
    ...
} 

@Component
public class CountryWriter implements ItemWriter<CountryDTO> {
    @Autowired
    private CountrySplit countrySplit;
    ...
} 

@Component
public class CountrySplit {
    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository repository;
    ...
} 


public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long> 
{
}
```

**And the error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'countryBatch': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'countryWriter'; nested exception is org. 
springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'countryWriter': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'countrySplit'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'countrySplit': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'countryRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 
'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': 
org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFa
ctoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$24da9e51 does not support circular 
references
```

I couldn't see the circular dependencies problem.

Comment: How is `CountryRepository` implemented?

Comment: Let spring-boot manage bean dependencies. Remove `DependsOn` and don't make datasource and entityManagerFactory a parameter and instead reference the bean, e.g. `result.setDataSource(dataSource())`

Comment: @jingx It is not implemented, I mean, it's only the interface that spring data need to perform operations to my entity. About CountryRepository I don't have any more code.

Comment: @jny I already did that. But the error is the same. :(

Comment: Sorry, but you dumping like 200 lines of code on us?! Please read about creating a minimal viable complete example ( stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ).